# Python convert multidimensional numpy array into multiple 1d numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I stacked 56 lots of 2D numpy arrays of size (100,13) using `numpy.dstack` so that my shape of X is:

```
X.shape
(56, 100, 13)
```

Now I want to divide this along its depth into 56*100 lots of 1D arrays of length 13.

I tried this `L = numpy.split(X[0],(100,13), axis =2)`, however I do not get the correct result.

Any suggestions?

Comment: short answer: `X.reshape(56*1000, 13)`

Comment: Are you looking for `L =  X.reshape(-1, 13)`?

Comment: Does reshaping it like that preserve the order of the pixels along the depth axis (the axis of length 13)?

Comment: @spicyburrito why not try a simple example a = np.arange(3*4*2).reshape(3, 4, 2) .... b = a.reshape(-1, 2) ... run and see if that is what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of using reshape to solve it, with some examples showing the order of the new 1D data after reshaping:

```
In [96]: X = np.random.rand(56, 100, 13)

In [97]: Y = X.reshape(56*100, 13)

In [98]: (X[0, 1, :] == Y[1, :]).all()
Out[98]: True

In [99]: (X[0, 99, :] == Y[99, :]).all()
Out[99]: True

In [100]: (X[1, 0, :] == Y[100, :]).all()
Out[100]: True
```